# linq and DTO property interpolation

Tags: c#, linq

In the below query I order by "Category1":

```
var ExampleValues = (from values in ExampleAllRecorsds
 group values by new { values.Category1, values.Date.Value.Month } into x
 orderby x.Key.Category1
 select new ExamplesDto()
 {
     ExampleId = exampleId,
     Row = x.Key.Category1,
     Month = x.Key.Month,
 }).ToList();
```

I have other properties that I want to order my query by, depending on another variable. It could be ordering by Category2, Category3, etc.

What I want to do is change the ordering of this query between my CategoryX properties without needing to wholesale repeat the query in a `switch` statement.

For example, this is how I would think to do it *with* a switch. Notice that this is repeating a lot of code.

```
switch(categoryVar){

case "Category1":
    var ExampleValues = (from values in ExampleAllRecorsds
         group values by new { values.Category1, values.Date.Value.Month } into x
         orderby x.Key.Category1     // the only change
         select new ExamplesDto()
         {
             ExampleId = exampleId,
             Row = x.Key.Category1,
             Month = x.Key.Month,
         }).ToList();
    break;
case "Category2":
    var ExampleValues = (from values in ExampleAllRecorsds
         group values by new { values.Category1, values.Date.Value.Month } into x
         orderby x.Key.Category2    // the only change
         select new ExamplesDto()
         {
             ExampleId = exampleId,
             Row = x.Key.Category2,
             Month = x.Key.Month,
         }).ToList();
    break
    ...  
}
```

How do I not repeat myself?

Comment: I don't understand what you're after. Can you give an example of what you _don't_ want that uses a switch? That might give a better idea about what you do want.

Comment: Ok, give me a minute. Thank you for the your attention.

Comment: Is this used in LinQ for EF, or just for normal list?

Comment: EF. this AllRecords are from a entity and this query is to group data according with a category.

Comment: What i tried to do was $"values.{categoryVar}" but this doesn't work especially inside the Dto.

Comment: I modified the body of your question - hopefully that's still accurate to what you want.

Comment: did you try `orderby categoryVar == "Category1" ? x.Key.Category1 : x.Key.Category2`? If that doesn't work I'm pretty sure EF can navigate to properties by string, so you could try `orderby $"x.Key.{categoryVar}"`

Comment: Actually i did the first suggestion on another part, but on linq i tried your second suggestion, i'll try again...
`Category = category1 == "Category1" ? entity.Category1 : category1 == "Category2" ? entity.Category2 : category1 == "Category3" ? entity.Category3 : category1 == "Category4" ? entity.Category4 : entity.Category1,`

Comment: @DanScott how would be with 2 itens on the group by? like `$"new x.Key.{categoryVar}, {limits.Date.Value}"` ? 
 i can see it working if i remove the order by and the property that belongs to the second value on the group by.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using an extra library and are on .net Core you could try: 
[System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core)

I'm pretty sure there is a System.linq.dynamic for Framework as well, you can check nuget for both